# How can I manually specify text for legends in sympy.plotting.plot?

Tags: python, plot, sympy, legend

I am using `sympy.plotting.plot` for plotting different functions. I want
to add manual labels.

This is what I tried, however, I would like to have ‘Foo1’ in line 1 of
the legend and ‘Foo2’ in line 2 of the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x')

sym.plotting.plot(x ** 2, 2 * x ** 2, legend = True, label = ['Foo1', 'Foo2'])
```

[image]

Can anyone help? This would be great!

Many thanks in advance, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

`sympy.plotting` is unable to do that with the keyword argument `label`. The procedure to get your desired result is something like this:

```py
p = sym.plotting.plot(x ** 2, 2 * x ** 2, legend = True, show=False)
p[0].label = "Foo1"
p[1].label = "Foo2"
p.show()
```

In my opinion, this is awful. If you are interested in a better plotting module, take a look at [SymPy Plotting Backends](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/), which implements the behavior your are looking for:

```py
import spb
spb.plot(x ** 2, 2 * x ** 2, legend = True, label = ['Foo1', 'Foo2'])
```

[image]